# How to configure gradle to retrieve all dependencies and plugins from a Nexus Repository

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

We have a React Native App and we have to download all the dependecies fo my App from the Company Nexus repository.

We have a maven gruop repository with lot of repository inside. One of them is a maven proxy repository that point to: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/b

We configured our `settings.grandle` like this:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'URL_OF_NEXUS_GROUP_MAVEN_REPO' }
  }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
      maven { url 'URL_OF_NEXUS_GROUP_MAVEN_REPO' }
  }
}
```

We are able to download all dependecies from our repo but we encounter only a problem during build and compile: one of our dependencies in package.json is react-native-keychain and it has this `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.adarshr:gradle-test-logger-plugin:2.0.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "com.adarshr.test-logger"
```

Why this setting is not overwritten like the others by our `settings.gradle`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've solved deleting the changes in settings.gradle ad creating a init.gradle in HOME/.gradle with this contents:

```
allprojects {
  ext.RepoConfigurator = {
    maven {
      url = uri('URL_OF_NEXUS_GROUP_MAVEN_REPO')
    }
         
  }
  buildscript.repositories RepoConfigurator
  repositories RepoConfigurator
}
apply plugin: EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin
 
class EnterpriseRepositoryPlugin implements Plugin<Gradle> {
    void apply(Gradle gradle) {
        gradle.settingsEvaluated { settings ->
            settings.pluginManagement {
                repositories {
                    maven { url 'URL_OF_NEXUS_GROUP_MAVEN_REPO' }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```